# Room freeze when use coroutine flow->collect

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using Room (v. 2.2.1) with coroutines support (v. 1.3.2) and following setup

```
@Entity(tableName = "simple_table")
data class SimpleEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0
) 

@Dao
interface SimpleDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM simple_table WHERE id = :id")
    fun getRecord(id: Long): Flow<SimpleEntity?>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(entity: SimpleEntity)
}
```

Then after I inserted data into simple_table with autogenerated id 1 I trying to query

```
db.simpleDao.getRecord(1).collect {
  //fetch data
}
db.close()
```

The `db.close()` never get reached. It just freeze in `collect()` method. If I change code to

```
db.simpleDao.getRecord(1).first {
  //fetch data
}
```

or

```
db.simpleDao.getRecord(1).take(1).collect {
  //fetch data
}
```

then it works without any issue. But why plain `collect()` never ends their execution? What I missed in my Room configuration to make it work properly as it should?

Comment: This smells like a library bug.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and **had solved it**.

**Code after .collect {}** does not work in the same coroutine!
If you write like that:

```
    MainScope().launch {

        db.simpleDao.getRecord(1).collect {
            //fetch data
        }
        /**
         * My other code that will be freezed
         * */

    }
```

You should write like that:

```
    MainScope().launch {

        launch { //new coroutine
            db.simpleDao.getRecord(1).collect {
                //fetch data
            }
            // No code here
        }
        /**
         * My other code that will not be freezed
         * */

    }
```

I think this is all because of slot.awaitPending() that's invoked waiting new value for collecting.